# In Model.State Validation is invalid

Tags: file-upload, asp.net-core-mvc

i trying to upload the multiple images using asp.netcore mvc. i made property of pic in which i save the url path of image. when compiler hits the Model.State it gives Validation invalid. i also created property image in which image url saved. that property type is IFORMFILE. i am using sql to save pic information and using model for code. when i check in model state i find the error message of pic field is required.

```
namespace ehouse.Controllers
{

 public class AddPropertyRentController1 : Controller
    {

        Rentdb DB =new Rentdb();
        private IWebHostEnvironment _IWebHostEnvironment;
        public AddPropertyRentController1(IWebHostEnvironment IWebHostEnvironment)
        {
            _IWebHostEnvironment = IWebHostEnvironment;
        }
        public IActionResult aprent()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult aprent([Bind] RentModel ar)
        {
            if (ar.imge1 != null)
            {
                string folder = "photos/photo/";
                folder += ar.imge1.FileName + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                



                ar.pic1 = folder;

                string serverFolder = Path.Combine(_IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, folder);
                ar.imge1.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(serverFolder, FileMode.Create));
                
            }
            if (ar.imge2 != null)
            {
                string folder = "photos/photo/";
                folder += ar.imge2.FileName + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                
                ar.pic2 = folder;
                string serverFolder = Path.Combine(_IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, folder);
                ar.imge2.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(serverFolder, FileMode.Create));
               
            }
            if (ar.imge3 != null)
            {
                string folder = "photos/photo/";
                folder += ar.imge3.FileName + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                ar.pic3 = folder;
                string serverFolder = Path.Combine(_IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, folder);
                ar.imge3.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(serverFolder, FileMode.Create));
            }
            if (ar.imge4 != null)
            {
                string folder = "photos/photo/";
                folder += ar.imge4.FileName + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                ar.pic4 = folder;
                string serverFolder = Path.Combine(_IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, folder);
                ar.imge4.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(serverFolder, FileMode.Create));
            }
            if (ar.imge5 != null)
            {
                string folder = "photos/photo/";
                folder += ar.imge5.FileName + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                ar.pic5 = folder;
                string serverFolder = Path.Combine(_IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, folder);
                ar.imge5.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(serverFolder, FileMode.Create));
            }
            if (ar.imge6 != null)
            {
                string folder = "photos/photo/";
                folder += ar.imge6.FileName + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                ar.pic6 = folder;
                string serverFolder = Path.Combine(_IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, folder);
                ar.imge6.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(serverFolder, FileMode.Create));
            }
            if (ar.imge7 != null)
            {
                string folder = "photos/photo/";
                folder += ar.imge7.FileName + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                ar.pic7 = folder;
                string serverFolder = Path.Combine(_IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, folder);
                ar.imge7.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(serverFolder, FileMode.Create));

            }
            if (ar.imge8 != null)
            {
                string folder = "photos/photo/";
                folder += ar.imge8.FileName + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                ar.pic8 = folder;
                string serverFolder = Path.Combine(_IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, folder);
                ar.imge8.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(serverFolder, FileMode.Create));
            }
            if (ar.imge9 != null)
            {
                string folder = "photos/photo/";
                folder += ar.imge9.FileName + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                ar.pic9 = folder;
                string serverFolder = Path.Combine(_IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, folder);
                ar.imge9.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(serverFolder, FileMode.Create));
            }
            if (ar.imge10 != null)
            {
                string folder = "photos/photo/";
                folder += ar.imge10.FileName + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                ar.pic10 = folder;
                string serverFolder = Path.Combine(_IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, folder);
                ar.imge10.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(serverFolder, FileMode.Create));
            }
            try
            {
                
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                   

                    
                    string res = DB.Saverecord(ar);
                    string pics = DB.imagedb(ar);

                    

                    
                    TempData["msg"] = res;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TempData["msg"] = ex.Message;
            }
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

RentModel

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace eHouse.Models
{

```
public class RentModel
{

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string tittle { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public string descrip { get; set; }

    public string areaUnit { get; set; }
    public int area { get; set; }
    public string province { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }W
    public string stadress { get; set; }
    //public string features { get; set;}
    public string bathroom { get; set; }
    public string furnished { get; set; }
    public string p_type { get; set; }
    public string bedroom { get; set; }
    public int p_id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string? pic1 { get; set; }
    [Required]

    public IFormFile imge1 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string? pic2 { get; set; }
    
    public IFormFile imge2 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string? pic3 { get; set; }
   
    public IFormFile imge3 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string? pic4 { get; set; }
  
    public IFormFile imge4 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string? pic5 { get; set; }
   
    public IFormFile imge5 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string? pic6 { get; set; }
   
    public IFormFile imge6 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string? pic7 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public IFormFile imge7 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string? pic8 { get; set; }
    public IFormFile imge8 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string? pic9 { get; set; }

    public IFormFile imge9 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string? pic10 { get; set; }
   
    public IFormFile imge10 { get; set; }
    
    public int r_id
    {
        get; set;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: I assume you're familiar with the concept of ending sentences with `.`. Please do that in the future. You have the same thing in every one of your questions.

Comment: Could you please share the model for the RentModel? Besides, according to the error message it looks like pic9 is null when you are using it.

Comment: I add the RentModel kindly check

Comment: The pic9 is required inside the model, this means if the client view doesn't post the pic9 to the backend, the model validation will always failed even you have set the pic9 inside the controller method. Since the model validation will just validate the model not the changed model.